# I want my search bar to look for nested value but I have troubles with my WHERE LIKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, Phones and Records, they are related to each other by the phone.ID.

I have a search bar for each index. On each, I've implemented a search bar where user can searching for their phone by their IMEI.

Recently, I've added a `ref_number` column in the Phones table.

So into the `views/phones/index`, it does works well. 
However, in the `views/records/index`, it doesn't work because of the phone relation. What I meant by that is that I could access it in my `phone.rb` like this :

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
    where('imei LIKE :term OR ref_number LIKE :term', term: "%#{term}%")
  else
    order('id DESC')
  end
end
```

But I can not in my `record.rb` using this :

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
    where('imei LIKE :term OR phone.ref_number LIKE :term', term: "%#{term}%")
  else
    order('id DESC')
  end
end
```

Here's my `records_controller`, my `phones_controller` looks clearly the same :

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
    @records = Record.search(params[:term]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Does any of you knows how I could access the value `phone.ref_number` in something like this ?

Thanks,

Raphaël.

Comment: How are those 2 related?

Comment: Yup, they are related.

Comment: @Nermin 1) You said "this date", what do you mean by this? 2) You said "it doesn't work because of the phone relation", what do you mean by this? 3) It would help us if you could show code of your `Phone` and `Record` models, and also `PhonesController#index` and `RecordsController#index` 4) Also, it would also help if you could update your post to add something like "I expect something something..., but currently it's not working because something something", and be specific about them. This would also help us. ty.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I've updated my question, do not hesitate if you need something more.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using normal Rails conventions then the table for the Phone model will be `phones.ref_number`, even if the association within Rails is just `phone`, because you're writing raw SQL at this point.

You may need to also use `joins(:phone).where(.. )`, as I'm not sure that ActiveRecord will do it for you when you're writing raw SQL like that.